# Select query for report with known number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have written a select query for a report that fetches count for months in a year. The resulting table looks like..

```
rep_name    month    year    count
----------------------------------
 repo1       1       2013     5
 repo1       4       2013     6
 repo1       12      2013     18
 repo1       2      2014     20   
   .
   .
```

And so on. The desired output in my case is a table which shows records across all months. Even if there is no data available, it needs to show the record with a count 0 like

```
rep_name    month    year    count
----------------------------------
 repo1       1       2013     5
 repo1       2       2013     0
 repo1       3       2013     0
 repo1       4       2013     6
 repo1       5       2013     0
 repo1       6       2013     0
 repo1       7       2013     0
 repo1       8       2013     0
 repo1       9       2013     0
 repo1       10      2013     0
 repo1       11      2013     0
 repo1       12      2013     18
   . 
   .
   .
```

Have had a similar query before but the set of data there was limited to 3. 
[select statement to always return 3 rows on execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983636/select-statement-to-always-return-3-rows-on-execution)

In this case, i cannot be sure how many months would be displayed. it depends on available data.

Comment: RIGHT JOIN with a table containing only months

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright what you want to do is ge yourself a [Calendar Table](http://michaelmorley.name/how-to/create-date-dimension-table-in-sql-server) these are incredibly useful and every database should have one. On the off chance that that link goes down here is the script included.

```
/** Create Date Dimension Table **/
/* Create First numbers table for key generation */
CREATE TABLE Numbers_Small (Number INT);

INSERT INTO Numbers_Small
VALUES (0)
    ,(1)
    ,(2)
    ,(3)
    ,(4)
    ,(5)
    ,(6)
    ,(7)
    ,(8)
    ,(9);
GO

/* Create Second numbers table for key generation */
CREATE TABLE Numbers_Big (Number_Big BIGINT);

INSERT INTO Numbers_Big (Number_Big)
SELECT (tenthousands.number * 10000 + thousands.number * 1000 + hundreds.number * 100 + tens.number * 10 + ones.number) AS number_big
FROM numbers_small tenthousands
    ,numbers_small thousands
    ,numbers_small hundreds
    ,numbers_small tens
    ,numbers_small ones;
GO

/* Create Date Dimension Table */
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimDate] (
    [DateKey] [int] NOT NULL
    ,[Date] [datetime] NOT NULL
    ,[Day] [char](10) NULL
    ,[DayOfWeek] [smallint] NULL
    ,[DayOfMonth] [smallint] NULL
    ,[DayOfYear] [smallint] NULL
    ,[PreviousDay] [datetime] NULL
    ,[NextDay] [datetime] NULL
    ,[WeekOfYear] [smallint] NULL
    ,[Month] [char](10) NULL
    ,[MonthOfYear] [smallint] NULL
    ,[QuarterOfYear] [smallint] NULL
    ,[Year] [int] NULL
    );
GO

/* Create Date Key and Date Fields */
INSERT INTO [DimDate] (
    DateKey
    ,DATE
    )
SELECT number_big
    ,DATEADD(day, number_big, '1900-01-01') AS DATE
FROM numbers_big
WHERE DATEADD(day, number_big, '1900-01-01') BETWEEN '1900-01-01'
        AND '2030-12-31'
ORDER BY number_big;
GO

/* Update all other fields with appropriate data. */
UPDATE [DimDate]
SET Day = DATENAME(DW, DATE)
    ,DayOfWeek = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATE)
    ,DayOfMonth = DAY(DATE)
    ,DayOfYear = DATEPART(DY, DATE)
    ,PreviousDay = DATEADD(DAY, - 1, DATE)
    ,NextDay = DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATE)
    ,WeekOfYear = DATEPART(WK, DATE)
    ,Month = DATENAME(MONTH, DATE)
    ,MonthOfYear = MONTH(DATE)
    ,QuarterOfYear = DATEPART(Q, DATE)
    ,Year = YEAR(DATE);
GO

/* Drop Temp Tables */
DROP TABLE Numbers_Small;

DROP TABLE Numbers_Big;
```

So now once you have that table added simply do a `LEFT JOIN` to your DimDate table on Month and bam you're good to go.

Comment: Calendar tables will change your life!

Answer (score 1):

This code dynamically extracts **min** and **max** dates from your source table, then recursively generates table with dates between **min** and **max** dates and finally joins source table with generated dates. No updates, inserts, DDL, etc - one CTE :)

```
/*
-- generating fake #your_table
select * into #your_table
from (values 
    ('repo1', 1, 2013, 5),
    ('repo1', 4, 2013, 6),
    ('repo1', 12, 2013, 18),
    ('repo1', 2, 2014, 20)) as your_table(rep_name, [month], [year], [count]);
*/


with min_max_days as (
    select min(dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(year, [year]-1900, dateadd(month, [month], '1900-01-01')))) [min_day]
    , max(dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(year, [year]-1900, dateadd(month, [month], '1900-01-01')))) [max_day] from #your_table),

[base] as (
select (select year([min_day]) from min_max_days) [year], (select month([min_day]) from min_max_days) [month], (select [min_day] from min_max_days) [date]
union all
select year(dateadd(month, 1, [date])) [year], month(dateadd(month, 1, [date])) [month], dateadd(month, 1, [date])
from [base]
where [date] < (select [max_day] from min_max_days))

select isnull(t.rep_name, 'repo1') [rep_name]
, b.[month]
, b.[year]
, isnull(t.[count], 0) [count]
from [base] b
left join #your_table t on b.[year] = t.[year]
    and b.[month] = t.[month];
```

### **Output**

```
rep_name    month   year    count
--------------------------------
repo1       1       2013    5
repo1       2       2013    0
repo1       3       2013    0
repo1       4       2013    6
repo1       5       2013    0
repo1       6       2013    0
repo1       7       2013    0
repo1       8       2013    0
repo1       9       2013    0
repo1       10      2013    0
repo1       11      2013    0
repo1       12      2013    18
repo1       1       2014    0
repo1       2       2014    20
```

**And please check [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7136e/3)**

Comment: Thanks! will try this. But why is it showing repo0 in few cases? it needs to be repo1 throughout

Comment: It was my assumption that empty rows must have different repo numer than original ones. Now I chganged them to repo1. Please check.